# No scss styling at all in my theme after updating to Shopware 6.5.4 (./bin/watch-storefront)

Tags: sass, proxy, shopware, shopware6

I switched to the newest version of Shopware 6 which is 6.5.4 with this upgrade I noticed that my theme isn't loading normally through the hot proxy server I have 0 scss styling 0 js (html changes that i have done are showing on the developer tool in the browser) inside of my theme and I cant see the problem I compared everything in my theme in the last version and the one with the new version and they are 100% identical still I get this with hot proxy:

[image: hot proxy]

and loading it normally works fine:
[image]

Comment: I tried using a newly created theme with only a background color of red and it does the same thing the scss style  is being ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling and reinstalling did it for me .... I did it 3 times but for some reason only the third time worked.