# Invalid theme name error when trying to install valid Shopware theme

Tags: shopware6

I wrote a simple demo Shopware theme plugin after consulting [Shopware's official theme guide](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/themes/) and themes created by `bin/console theme:create`. I was able to install it successfully, but I failed to assign it to the Storefront sales channel using `bin/console theme:change` which throws an `ERROR Invalid theme name` but without giving any more details like a file name (`composer.json`, `theme.json`) or line number.

The admin web UI shows the theme in "My Extensions" -> "Themes", but not in the "Storefront" -> "Theme" -> "change" UI dialog.

[Shopware CLI](https://sw-cli.fos.gg) validates the theme without any warning:
`shopware-cli extension validate custom/plugins/IngoSDemoTogetherTheme` results in `INFO Validation has been successful`.

In the IDE (PhpStorm 2023.3 with activated and licensed Shopware and Symfony support) `composer.json` shows no error or warning, while `src/Resources/theme.json` is full of warnings and recommendations, all of which contradict the official theme guide like `Missing required property 'version' = 2` and `Property 'author' is not allowed` , `Property 'style' is not allowed`  etc.

Here are the sections of both JSON files that I think define the theme name:

`src/Resources/theme.json`

```json
  "name": "IngoSDemoTogetherTheme",
...
  "views": [
     "@IngoSDemoTogetherTheme"
```

`src/composer.json`

```json
  "name": "ingo-s/ingo-s-demo-together-theme",
```

What is wrong, and more importantly, how to find that out?

Is there any way to find out what exactly causes the error without reading more documentation or doing trial-and-error coding?

Comment: Did you do other changes or only in `composer.json` and `theme.json`? I would suggest to try again creating a clean theme and making your changes step by step until it breaks. Other than that, I wouldn't know of any functionality in shopware to debug this.

Comment: Also further checking the `theme:change command` in `vendor/shopware/storefront/Theme/Command/ThemeChangeCommand.php` we can see that the error is only thrown if no theme with the provided `technicalName`  can be found. TechnicalName is the name provided in `theme.json`

Comment: Since the command is looking for the theme with the specified `technicalName` in the database, you can further debug there if it's even installed correctly. The table `theme` should have your custom theme. Since the `theme:change` command fails, it's probably not registered probably in the database. And maybe you can try to uninstall and reinstall your theme

Comment: @AlexBerger Rebuilt the container, reinstalled and activated the theme using the admin UI. Now I can even see and assign the theme to the storefront. So far, so good. But I still don't understand the error and how to fix and prevent it in the future.

Comment: Erratic behavior that reminds of [No scss styling at all in my theme after updating to Shopware 6.5.4 (./bin/watch-storefront)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76874599/no-scss-styling-at-all-in-my-theme-after-updating-to-shopware-6-5-4-bin-watch) Hope that I can reproduce it eventually so that I can open an issue.